# Power BI with SharePoint Hosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerbi

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Power BI inside a SharePoint App. There would be a list and it would be possible to display a report with data from that list.

I want to know if the following are possible:

- Show reports
- Create reports through SharePoint Hosted App

I read many things and some said that it isnt secure to pass the token using a client side language but i think it would be fine saving it in a local file or something...

If the above arent possible do you think they could be using a Provider Hosted App?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already had a look at Power BI Embedded: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/

You have different API's and SDK's as documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/power-bi-embedded/